# How to render videos in PowerPoint slide in Add-ins using Unsplash API (JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, powerpoint, office-js, office-addins, powerpoint-web-addins

```
const btnClickVideo = async (Videourl:any) => {
    console.log("video Onclicked",Videourl)
    const resp = await VideoApi.getVideo(Videourl);
    console.log("clicked in video")
    console.log("video resp", resp);
  };

 <button title="Click" type="button" onClick={() => btnClickVideo(response.link)} >   <video width="150" height="150" controls >
```

this the code where a try to get resp

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev if it is possible so can you please share the link?

Comment: Which link do you like to see?

Comment: i have searched about insert the video from task pane to slide in power point but i didnt find the any clue about it, and there are some post which is saying its not possible 
so i just want to know sir is this possible to insert the video from taskpane to slide ?